# Let $x_1$=1 and $x_{n+1}$=$\frac{x_n}{2} +3 \forall n \geq 1$. Show: (i) ($X_n$) is monotonically increasing. (ii) ($X_n$) converges to 6.

Tags: real-analysis

This is what I have so far....

Since $x_1$=1 and $x_{n+1}$=$\frac{x_n}{2} +3 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, we obtain
$x_2=\frac{x_1}{2} +3
     =\frac{7}{2} \geq  x_1$

Assume that this is true for every natural number K, that is 
$x_{k+1}$ $\ge$ $x_k$. 
We need to show that $x_k+2$ $\ge$ $x_{k+1}$.

$x_{k+2}$ = $f(x_{k+1})$
        $\ge$ $f(x_k)$
        = $x_{k+1}$

Therefore, by the Principal of Mathematical Induction, $(x_n)$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Do you mean $x_{n+1}=x_n/2+3$?

Comment: I assumed so and edited accordingly.

Comment: yes. please re-edit. I tried to but made the same mistake again

Comment: Compute that $6-x_{n+1}=\frac12(6-x_n)$. From there, it should be easy to finish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

First we show that the sequence is monotonic.

$x_1 = 1 \qquad x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}x_n + 3 \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Show that the sequence is monotonically increasing by looking at the ratio between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$.

$$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}x_n+3}{x_n} =\quad ... \quad  \geq 1 \quad \forall n \quad \therefore \mathrm{monotonically\ increasing} $$

Show that the sequence converges to 6 by the following

$$ 6 - x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(6-x_n) $$